# Пропал жесткий диск

Tags: ssd

ноутбук gigabyte g7 me

Стояла(ит) OS Fedora 38, и все работало нормально, но недолго, система начала зависать и иногда приходилось отключать через физическую кнопку. И началась какая то ерунда то ли с жестким диском то ли c BIOS, по нескольку раз приходилось запускать через лайв флешку и искать причину и я обнаружил что жесткий диск то бывает видим (и тогда как ни странно все запускается нормально), то снова пропадет(как в bios, так и в меню настроек при запуске c флэш(disk capacity - unknown), а консольные утилиты обнаруживают только liveUSB), осмотрел ssd визуально на предмет физических повреждений, сняв крышку ноутбука и он как "из коробки" (года не прошло с покупки).
В биосе пробовал всяческие манипуляции с настройками, но ничто из этого не помогло.Не знаю что прикладывать к этому вопросу, кроме этого скрина. Может я мог бы что то еще попробовать перед тем как нести его в сервис?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прежде чем в сервис нести, можно попробовать воткнуть его в другой компьютер или переходник SATA -> USB. Могу контроллёр на диске умереть, могла плата на самом компьютере повредиться, вариантов много.